# Is the form "with which" used correctly in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

> Private sales, therefore, represent a way with which auction houses can operate somehow as dealers and galleries.

Is the form "with which" used correctly in this sentence? If not, what is the right form? Thank you.

Comment: ...a way by which....that is, by means of which...

Comment: It helps if you split the subordinate clause off into a separate sentence, and you get something like: "Auction houses can operate somehow as dealers and galleries in this way". ("in this way" sounds by far the most natural.) When you join it together, you replace "in this way" with "a way in which". (This is fairly standard advice on how to construct a subordinate clause in English.)

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: *A way in which ...* sounds the most idiomatic to me. *A way by which ...* is probably more in keeping with the formal register of the sentence. *With* seems to want a more concretely thing-like antecedent like *tool*.

Comment: @StuartF - not sure that  “a way in which” is more idiomatic than “a way by which” , and not necessarily so formal: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+way+by+which%2C+a+way+in+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20way%20by%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20way%20in%20which%3B%2Cc0